# How to stop angular service worker from caching facebook pixel?

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, facebook-pixel

I have enabled facebook pixel into my angular webApp. But it only works on if i hard refresh. After that the request gets triggered via service worker and not getting registered in the facebook pixel extension.
I have tried including the links into the dataGroups.
I have also tried the ngsw-bypass=true query param
[image]

Everything works fine if i remove the service worker from my app.

```js
ngsw-config.json
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "dataGroups": [
  {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": ["https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js","https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/**"],
      "cacheConfig": {
          "maxSize": 0,
          "maxAge": "0u",
          "strategy": "freshness"
      }
  }
  ],
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
load() {

      if (!this.loadOk) {

        (function (f: any, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
            if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                n.callMethod ?
                    n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
            }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
            n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
            t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js?ngsw-bypass=true');
        // (window as any).fbq.disablePushState = true; //not recommended, but can be done
        (window as any).fbq('init', '1117176809040790');
 
        (window as any).fbq('track', 'PageView');
        this.loadOk = true;
        console.log('Facebook pixel init run!')
      }
      else {
        (window as any).fbq('track', 'PageView');
        console.log('Facebook PageView event fired!')
      }


  }
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you dont need to add anything to the ng-sw for facebook connect. Also the image shown was cache from disk, not from service worker. I would just remove the facebook api data group. And it should work just fine.

Comment: Hi Henrik, added another image below. What i meant is that the request is triggered from the worker as shown in the new image and it doesn't get logged in pixel extention. 
Adding The data group part is one among the various fixes that I have tried adding. I just doesn't work with or without it. Like I already mentioned in the question that pixel works perfectly fine if I remove service worker from the app.